# I need more Lollipops to satisfy that greedy witch!

Tags: candy-box

The Sorceress wants lollipops. Millions of lollipops. My humble little lollipop farm is producing 100 lollipops per second and I just can't keep up with her voracious hunger for suckers. Is there any way to increase my production of lollipops?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have three good options here:

Option one is to simply focus on increasing your candy production, via grinding quests, use of **The Amulet**, and the sorceress's various *Faster Candy* upgrades -  combined with the Candy Converter (chance to?) drop from the Necromancer at the Castle Stairs, you can increase your lollipop production by  as much as 50-100%.

Option Two is the **Wishing Well**, which will give you an 8x multiplier to your *current stockpile* of lollipops. To get optimal use out of this, it's best to let the game run for several hours, until you have a few million Lollipops to start with. Then use the wish to have eight times as many millions. Works well in combination with Option One to increase the rate of candy production, which can then be converted back into lollipop production.

Option Three is the one that you're probably looking for though, which *triples the output of the Lollipop Farm*, to a whopping ***300 LP/S***. To do that, you'll need to acquire the **Horn of Plenty**, which can be had by defeating the Cow King in the Cow Level. To get to the Cow Level, you'll need to use the cauldron to make several **G.M.O.O.H.** potions. Each use of one has a one in four chance of sending you to the Cow Level. If you can clear the Cow Level, you'll get several thousand candies, and of course, the Horn.

Comment: I got the candy converter from the castle stairs level, not the underwater cavern level

Comment: as posted above. but you will need lots of lolipops in your farm (i have 200,000) and the horn but still only 100 LP/S.

Comment: That's where I got it, too

Comment: Probably my mistake. Edited until someone comes along and yells at me that they got it from the whale.